# Matching a whitespace or emptry string using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this regex in **java**

```
String pattern = "(\\s)(\\d{2}-)(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)(-\\d{4})(\\s)";
```

It works as intended but I have a new problem to get some valid dates:

**1st problem**:

If I have this String `It was at 22-febrero-1999 and 10-enero-2009 and 01-diciembre-2000` I should get another string as `febrero-enero-diciembre` and I only get `febrero-enero`

**2nd problem**

If I have a single date in a String like `12-octubre-1989` I get an emptry String.

Why I have in my **pattern** to have whitespaces in the start and end of any date? because I have to catch only valid months in a String like `adsadasd 12-validMonth-2999 asd 11-validMonth-1989` I should get both **validMonth**, then never get a validMonth in a String like `asdadsad12-validMonth-1989 asdadsad 23-validMonth-1989` in the last one I only should get the last **validMonth**

**PD:** My java code is

```
String resultado = "";
String pattern = "(\\s)(\\d{2}-)(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)(-\\d{4})(\\s)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(fecha);
while (m.find()) {
    resultado += m.group().split("-")[1] + "-";
}
return (resultado.compareTo("") == 0 ? "" : resultado.substring(0, resultado.length() - 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a word boundary instead:

```
\\b(\\d{2}-)(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)(-\\d{4})\\b
```

And I believe some of the months can be optimized a little bit (it could reduce readability unfortunately, but should speed things up by a notch):

```
\\b(\\d{2}-)((?:en|febr)ero|ma(?:rz|y)o|abril|ju[ln]io|agosto|(?:septiem|octu|noviem|diciem)bre)(-\\d{4})\\b
```

Comment: I don't know very well how to improve REGEX because I have been using them for a week, I'm updating my code using simple String to match with REGEX.

Comment: @rokimoki That's okay, if it works for you, I'm glad :) Regex aren't learned in a few hours after all!

Comment: As far I understand you are grouping months with the same start and diferent ending, like ENero FEBRero EN|FEBRero, that's a good point of view, anyway I didn't realized that.

Comment: @rokimoki Yup, this relieves some of the pressure off the regex engine and reduce backtracking. Backtracking is one of the things that make regex work, but is one of the things that breaks them too (causes a lot of processing). But don't worry, your regex is safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using a `\b` instead of `\s`:

```
String pattern = "\\b(\\d{2}-)(enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)(-\\d{4})\\b";
```

This will only match strings where the first digit is not preceded by another word character (digit, letter, or underscore), and the last digit is not followed by a word character. I've also removed the capturing groups around the `\b`, because it would always be a zero-length string, if matched.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a word boundry as a delimeter.
I'd suggest to use either whitespace or NOT digit,
or no delimeter and put in a validation range of numbers for day/year.
This way you may catch more embeded dates that are in close
proximity (adjacent) to letters and underscore.

Something like:

```
 #  "(?<!\\d)\\d{2}-(?:enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre)-\\d{4}(?!\\d)"

 (?<! \d )         # Not a digit before us
 \d{2} -           # Two digits followed by dash
 (?:               # A month
      enero
   |  febrero
   |  marzo
   |  abril
   |  mayo
   |  junio
   |  julio
   |  agosto
   |  septiembre
   |  octubre
   |  noviembre
   |  diciembre
 )
 - \d{4}           # Dash followed by four digits
 (?! \d )          # Not a digit after us
```